# The usage of "could" and "can" in questions

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs, can-could

Which of the following is more appropriate?

> 1. Can you go?
> 2. Could you go?

Is there anything wrong in asking like this "Could you go?"

Comment: Strictly speaking, "Can you go?" means "Is it possible for you to go?", while "Could you go?" means "I'm asking you to go."  Often they are used interchangeably, however.  Can you add some context to your question?

Comment: Related: 1. [How do I choose between “can” and “could”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270478/how-do-i-choose-between-can-and-could?lq=1) 2. [What is the difference between 'can', 'could', 'may' and 'might'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99957/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-may-and-might) 3. [“Can/may/will you help me with this?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/can-may-will-you-help-me-with-this)

Comment: 4. [Can a hypothetical “could” main clause stand on its own without an expressed conditional?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180845/can-a-hypothetical-could-main-clause-stand-on-its-own-without-an-expressed-con) 5. [“It could/might/may be funny” — what is the correct usage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/it-could-might-may-be-funny-what-is-the-correct-usage)

Comment: @marilou, Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation

Comment: From the accepted answer in the older question: [*1. We could go (if we like / but we won't / etc.)
2. We can go (= We are capable of going / It is possible for us to go)*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/161/44619)

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [your previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325979/difference-between-can-could)? I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar, and both are correct.

'Can' is used more often if the person has more authority, and 'could' if the person has less authority or is trying not to be too difficult.

E.g., I would expect a IT manager to ask

> Can you reboot the server now?

and a timid neighbour to ask

> Could you keep the noise down, please?